# grouping 50,000 points on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to show some points on map (max 50,000) and I wonder how to do it. I know how to work with maps, and I saw [this article on google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering). But never seen anyone implementing it for more than 2000-3000 points. I mean, I saw a website that used another map with 50,000 and it took 11 sec to load the map on a pc and too forever on my phone. Is there any other way to do it?

I've also found [this article](http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/01/handling-large-amounts-of-markers-in-google-maps/) comparing different thirdparty librearies and their speed, but it is too old (2009). Also, I couldn't find any recomendations on this matter.

I also know that we can use [overlays on google map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays), so I can process the big picture and put it on top of the map. Cool, but then I will loose click functionalities. Like when you click on a group and it zoom in to show you that group, or double clicking.

Any Ideas?

Comment: You may want to take a look at marker clustering: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

Comment: @antonio I've already mentioned that in the 2nd line of my question.

Comment: Marker clustering is the way to go. The way you load your data will impact the performance of your app. You might want to experiment a few different things here. But I see no problem at all with **displaying** 50K markers in a clustered map if you do things correctly. Adjust the cluster size, fine-tune the settings, and you should have something you can work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the 2 important options you can play with:

```
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    gridSize: 100,
    minimumClusterSize: 10
});
```

As you can see in the below demo, you can plot and cluster 50K markers in less than a second...

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/2qdvjc4j/)</kbd>